# How to debug AA tests that are returning false positives in Google Optimize

Tags: ab-testing, google-optimize

We have run a number of AA tests to validate that our setup of Optimize is correct, however we are seeing a large number of false positives (i.e. Optimize is reporting clear leaders despite no differences in variants).

**Experience Setup**
We have now setup and run 6 experiences configured as AA tests.  Each experience is setup as an AB test with 2 variants that have no differences, and a 50/50 traffic split across each variant.  The primary objective is of type "events" and we've used different events as the primary objective across the different experiences.  Page targeting is set to all pages on domain (WHEN URL starts with https://www.ourdomain.com), and audience targeting is set to all visitors.  For every experience we ran diagnostics and Optimize installation was successfully validated.

**Experience reporting**
All 6 experiences have run to the point where Optimize is reporting either a clear leader or no clear leader found.  We would have expected most experiences tested to report inconclusive results (no clear leader) given there are no differences between the variants.  However of the 6 experiences, 2 are reporting that there is a clear leader based on the primary objective set.  This is a false positive rate of 33% - much higher than we would have expected.

How would we go about debugging what is causing this high rate of false positives?

Comment: It's highly unusual. We've run about 6 experiments (non-AA) with 10K-100K users and have yet to see a clear leader applied to any of them. Are your groups of equal sizes? e.g. you mention a 50-50 split, can you check your observed ratio matches your expected 50-50 ratio?